# Extend Nuxt3 runtime config dinamically

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxt3

Is it possible to extend Nuxt3 runtime config dinamically (for example retrieving more configurations from an api endpoint), ideally inside a server-only plugin?

I can't find any documentation for such case.